# How to copy data from one database/table to another database/table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have written the following query using the documentation at: [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm) to copy some data from a database/table on my production server to database/table on Sandbox server.

`COPY FROM username1/passwd1@<production_IP> to username2/passwd2@<sandbox_IP> INSERT TABLE_C (*) USING 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_C WHERE COL_A = 4884);`

However, I am constantly running into `Connection failed` error. Is there anything wrong with the query?

Comment: Does the destination table already exist?

Comment: Does `production_IP` stand for an IP address? If yes, that's not sufficient. You need to have TNS names set up and use an SID or a service name or use an easy connect name (which includes an  SID or a service name as well).

Comment: @Codo: Yes. Production IP stands for actual IP Address of the production server. Can you please tell me how the query changes after including the Service name. I cannot find the syntax in the documentation

Comment: How is the question "off-topic" ? please define "off-topic" here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a typical Oracle environment, you have TNS names set up. That's a service to lookup the connection parameters for Oracle instances given an SID or service name. In it's simplest form, TNS names is a file called `tnsnames.ora` located by the environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` (which points to the directory where the file is).

Given the SIDs `PROD` and `SANDBOX`, you can then copy the tables from the SQLPLUS command line utility:

```
COPY FROM username1/passwd1@PROD to username2/passwd2@SANDBOX
    INSERT TABLE_C (*) USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_C WHERE COL_A = 4884);
```

Please note that this COPY command only supports a limited set of Oracle datatypes: char, date, long, varchar2, number.

If you don't have TNS names set up, you'll need to know the host name or IP address, the port number and the service name. The syntax then becomes:

```
COPY FROM username1/passwd1@//192.168.3.17:1521/PROD_SERVICE to username2/passwd2@//192.168.4.17:1521/SANDBOX_SERVICE
    INSERT TABLE_C (*) USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_C WHERE COL_A = 4884);
```

To determine the SID and/or service name, you best have a look into the TNSNAMES.ORA file on the database server itself. If you are able to login to the database, you can use the following queries to determine the SID and service name (but don't ask me which is which):

```
select name from v$database;

select * from global_name;

select instance_number, instance_name, host_name from v$instance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy `gpl_project/gpl_project@gpldatar` to `gpl_project/gpl_project@gplrdp`. Replace `BGROUPMASTER` using `select * from BGROUPMASTER`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the solution that I used.   I created a link the remote database then used an INSERT command to populate the data.

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK database_link_name 
CONNECT TO my_user_name IDENTIFIED BY my_password
USING 'tns_name';

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM my_remote_table@database_link_name;
```

If you want to get rid of the database link after the work.  Use the following:

```
DROP DATABASE LINK database_link_name;
```

See this link for helpful information:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532217300346683472