# Copying/Appending non matching data between same table on different database servers

Tags: oracle11g

Following up on my earlier [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944156/how-to-copy-data-from-one-database-table-to-another-database-table) , is there a way to specify the condition for the records that would be copied over using the column names on the same table? i.e. I want to copy all data from sandbox server to production server for all rows where COL_A in sandbox that do not exist in the production server. So the intended `select` query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM <Sandbox><TABLE_C> WHERE <Sandbox><TABLE_C>COL_A NOT EXISTS (SELECT <production>COL_A FROM <production>TABLE_C)
```

i.e. all the records from sandbox to production where a matching `COL_A` could not be found

Comment: Are you trying to use the SQL*Plus `COPY` command as you were in the prior question?  Or are you trying to write a distributed query using database links?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand.  Do you have a database link between the two databases in question (i.e. `CREATE DATABASE LINK`) that you are trying to write distributed SQL to utilize?  Or are you trying to use the SQL*Plus `COPY` command?

Comment: I am using the SQL*Plus COPY command to perform the operation. The link above to my previous query shows the query suggested by @Codo using COPY FROM command of SQL*Plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Oracle specific syntax but something along these lines assuming that you are able to access them as linked servers -

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_C@prod_link
SELECT source.*
FROM TABLE_C source
LEFT JOIN TABLE_C@prod_link target
    ON source.COL_A = target.COL_A
WHERE target.COL_A IS NULL
```

where prod_link is a database link

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK 
  prod_link
CONNECT TO
  remote_username
IDENTIFIED BY 
  mypassword 
USING 'tns_service_name';
```

I do not have an Oracle instance running that I can try this on but it should work

Comment: By <production> tag, do you mean using `username1/passwd1@PROD`? I am looking for the syntax

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.  I was still not able to connect to the production server using the database link. I am not sure if the `prod_link` in you example meant the actual text or service name or host name. I tried doing all the permutations, but was constantly running into invalid username/password when running the `INSERT` query. I have given up on trying to do this through SQL command. Appreciate your efforts though !!

Comment: Are you able to run the SELECT query without the INSERT? It may be worth trying this the other way round with the query being run from production with the link back to your sandbox.