# Copy data from one database to another in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, oracle10g, bulkinsert

I have 2 Oracle databases and I frequently copy data from prod DB to test DB using TOAD, by generating insert scripts for Prod DB and running it on the test DB later.

I am trying to do it faster through a batch file.

I think that I can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944156/how-to-copy-data-from-one-database-table-to-another-database-table) solution but the DB has an `auto-increment` column. If I use this solution, would that column be affected? Do I need to change the script in some way? I haven't tried this so far as I have no access do the DB and would be able to test this only on Monday.

Is there a better way I can accomplish this? What I am essentially looking for is doing the whole copy procedure using a batch file, which would minimize the time I spend doing this using TOAD.

Also, it's fine by me if I can be guided in the right direction, if solution is not simple.

Comment: Although it can be very useful, the [COPY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apb.htm#CHDEAEDE) command will be obsoleted eventually, and it has some weird behavior.  The easiest, and fastest way to do this would be to use a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5005.htm#i2061505).

Comment: Export-Import can also be considered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure the two tables have the same structure.

Connect to the target database.

Create a public link to the source database. The user should have "CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK" system privilege to do this.

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK mylink
  CONNECT TO source_user IDENTIFIED BY source_password
  USING 'source_entry_in_tnsnames';
```

Copy the data:

```
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable@mylink;
```

If the primary key of the table comes from a sequence, set the sequence to - at least - the same value as in the source database:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE mysequence increment by 100000;
SELECT mysequence.nextval FROM DUAL;
ALTER SEQUENCE mysequence increment by 1;
```

Comment: The single quotes around `source_entry_in_tnsnames` are crucial; without them, you might spend some time wondering why Oracle throws errors at you. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm).